# Detach from IPython kernel without terminating it

Tags: python, ipython

Can someone please tell me how I can detach from an IPython kernel without terminating it?

I see in the documentation of `quit()` that there is a parameter `keep_kernel`, but unfortunately `quit(keep_kernel=True)` won't work.

Comment: This bug has meanwhile been fixed in IPython, see https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/8483

Answer (score 2):

If you are connected to the kernel via the IPython console client and are on a Unix-like OS, you can detach using Ctrl-\

Comment: Update: this no longer appears to be the case (at least with IPython 5.3.0 and Python 2.7.13).

Comment: Related to the above: https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter_console/issues/126