# Exit ipython console without killing the kernel

Tags: ipython

I'm connecting an IPython console to an existing kernel, via

```
ipython console --existing /path/to/your/kernel.json
```

However, when I exit the console, this kills the kernel:

```
In [8]: exit
Shutting down kernel
```

(same thing happens with ctrl+D, or any other method that I would normally use to get out of an IPython session). My intention is to have the ipython console temporarily as a debug tool for an IPython notebook. Obviously, I don't want the notebook kernel to die when I finish debugging. I don't want to use `qtconsole`, as all of this is running on a remote server, to which I'm connected via SSH/tmux. I can't easily "just close" the IPython console. I could supposedly kill the tmux pane, but that's rather cumbersome and just feels wrong. Any better options?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The console can be quit without killing the kernel: `quit(keep_kernel=True)`

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23680786/detach-from-ipython-kernel-without-terminating-it